# How to access bean from controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, javabeans

I have bean

```
<bean class="myprogram.FileList">
```

defined.

Now I wish this bean to be accessible from JSP. How to accomplish this?

First thought is to access bean somewhere in the controller method and put it to the model

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

    FileList fileList = // some code to access fileList bean

    model.addAttribute("fileList", fileList);

    return "home";
}
```

but probably this is ether not required or can be described somewhere in bean configuration?

**UPDATE**

The answer is `exposedContextBeanNames` parameter.

Comment: fileList should be INJECTED into this code!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, inject your bean into your controller using [@Autowired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) annotation:

```
@Autowired
private FileList fileList;
```

Then add it into your model like you already did: `model.addAttribute("fileList", fileList);`.

In JSP use [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) to access it. For e.g:

```
Some property from File List bean: <c:out value="${fileList.someProperty}"/>
```